# Create DB for practice in Toad/ Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi Stack Overflow Forum,

I've certain experience in SQL DML, DDL & easy procedures, but I would like to get a better understanding through practice.

To achieve that, I want to know if there is a way to create a dummy database using Toad or SQL Plus stored it in my PC & “play”. I've had the chance only to practice in the “real” database, in which I'm limited by my permissions.

Comment: A Google search on something like *Oracle developer version* might be useful.

Comment: You can also install a free sql server express version which will do everything you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best option is to download Oracle Express Edition, the free database for academic purposes (and more).

More info can be found here: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/xe.html

I know that it is only 11g, it is a little bit older. But for the DDL/DML training, it can be sufficient.

Download link: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html

Comment: I will try that. Thanks!